# Linq data structuring

Tags: linq, data-structures

I have two issues I'm struggling with LINQ. I appreciate if you could advise. I have 2 lists `rawStates` (storing rows of `entity-downtime-uptime-eventtype`) and `rawData` list storing products' in and out times from entity.

1. I want to select those elements from `rawStates` that occurred when still waiting for that entity to be processed

   ```
   foreach(var t in rawData)
       var s = rawStates
       //I am not sure if this single logic clause in Where is enough;
       .Where(o => o.Entity == t.Entity
           && o.DownDate > t.InTime
           && o.Update < t.OutTime)
       .ToList();
   ```
2. If I group my `rawData` by `productID` (there are multiple rows with same `ProductID`), how can I revert back this "s" to these groups so that for a `productID` I can group by `eventtype`, and `summarise` durations by `productID`?

Comment: I think you need to describe your two lists in more detail. Perhaps include class-level signatures?

Comment: Sounds like you need to look at doing a Join

Comment: Thanks guys. First one is trying to identify the Entity states the product t sees by comparing times.  I think the Where clause I use is not meeting this. So far, for the second, I did Joining by Entity, also included properties I wanted from the classes. There is a bit of an unstacking to do, since each product ends up seen multiple states at the same entity, and these differ each time... After the join, I can also select those satisfying condition in (1); which makes me think that equation is wrong.